# Sandbox refresh Question

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I am new to our Org. I am trying to refresh "partial copy" sandbox created by other person(who resigned the company). Currently I dont have log-in access to "partial copy" sandbox.

Can I still refresh the sandbox? If yes, how can I login to above sandbox? Is there any precautions do I need to consider?

Can someone help me here.

Thank You

Comment: Do you need to push something from 'Partial Copy' to Production prior the refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Once you refresh the sandbox, you can go to Production `Setup | Sandboxes` and log in from there, using your Production password

As others have noted, refreshing the sandbox blows away any pending work in that sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to log into a sandbox to refresh it. Refreshing takes place from the sandboxes view in the settings on your production org. (If you still have trouble with this, you will need assistance from your salesforce administrator).

Precautions would include being aware of any work on the sandbox that has not been migrated over to production yet. If its possible that there are other people working in that sandbox, make sure that any in-progress work has been committed to production with change sets prior to refreshing, otherwise all the work will be lost.